# txfonts kerning when exiting inline math mode

Tags: kerning, txfonts

I noticed strange behavior, when a hyphen follows inline math mode, if I am using the `txfonts` package.

If I use the Computer Modern font, the kerning of these two cases, while not precisely the same, seems compatible with what I would expect.

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\begin{document}
$S$-axis

\textit{S}-axis
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, using the `txfonts`, the disparity of these two cases becomes quite pronounced.

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\begin{document}
$S$-axis

\textit{S}-axis
\end{document}
```

[image]

I can, of course, resort to manual intervention, such as `$S\!$-axis`.  However, I was wondering if this is to be considered as a flaw in one of the font metrics, or if this is the sort of thing a user is expected to "roll with"?

Since `S` is a math-mode quantity, I would prefer to use the `$S$-axis` syntax.  But that seems problematic here.

Comment: It's not a kerning issue, but rather the box of `S` with `txfonts` is quite larger than the letter itself. Fixing such things is in part what led to `newtx`; so in a sense I'd say, as you wonder, that this is in fact a flaw in the `txfonts`.

Comment: @campa Thanks for the reply.  But I wonder, why does it only affect `$S$` and not `\textit{S}`, if it is the underlying `S` that is at fault?

Comment: Well, the italic letters have different bounding boxes for text and math even if they look alike; this is true also for CM (I remember a couple of related questions, I'll see if I can find them). So in the end I believe it still boils down to a (poor?) design choice in `txfonts`.

Comment: @campa I would welcome an answer where you put these thoughts down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The italic text letters come from the `OT1` (or `T1`) font with `it` shape, while the math `letters` from the `OML` encoded font (also with the `it` shape). Although they look very similar, they are not necessarily identical: for example, overlapping the text-italic and the math-italic `S` in Computer Modern shows that the math version is somewhat broader

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}\textit{S}}$S$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Furthermore, even they were identical in shape their bounding boxes would in general differ (sometimes a lot), as the following snippet shows for Computer Modern, `txfonts` and `newtx`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}
\mathsurround=0pt

CM: {\usefont{OT1}{cmr}{m}{it}\fbox{S}}
    {\usefont{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}\fbox{S}}

tx: {\usefont{OT1}{txr}{m}{it}\fbox{S}}
    {\usefont{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}\fbox{S}}

newtx: {\usefont{OT1}{ntxtlf}{m}{it}\fbox{S}}
       {\usefont{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}\fbox{S}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case of the `tx` fonts, it is clear that the bounding box of the math-italic `S` leaves a large empty space on the right of the glyph.

Coming to your question

> However, I was wondering if this is to be considered as a flaw in one of the font metrics, or if this is the sort of thing a user is expected to "roll with"?

I would say that it is a (poor?) design choice of the font. I won't go as far as to call it a flaw `;-)` because maybe there was a rationale behind it. Anyway, when I type math in a Times setting (well, never, but if I had to) I use the `newtx` fonts. The text version (`newtxtext`) is nowadays based on the TeX Gyre Termes, but (quote from the `newtx` documentation)

> `newtxmath` continues to use the `txfonts` math glyphs with many metric adjustments and some wholesale modifications.

Comment: An excellent and informative answer.  Thanks so much!