# When ending a sentence with the period, does it matter if the period is in maths mode or not?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, punctuation

Option 1:

```
The area of the disk is \[\pi r^2.\]
```

Option 2:

```
The area of the disk is \[\pi r^2\text{.} \]
```

Do they produce exactly the same result? If not, is the second option more "standard" than the first one?

Comment: What about the third option: `The area of the disk is $\pi r^2$.` ? This is what I would prefer.

Comment: @AlexG, sure. But what if I need to use the display style for some longer formulae?

Comment: Good point. I used to let it stay in math mode. But that's only my personal habit.

Comment: I had always omitted the period when a sentence ended with display math, but checking the math books within reach, it appears that the standard practice is to include the period.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

logically you should use `\text{.}`.

By default . will come from the font used for `\mathrm` which in pdflatex default is the same as the font used for `\textrm` ie the document default.

Even with the default font setup `.` and `\text{.}` may produce different fonts, eg in a theorem set in italic `\text{.}` will use the italic font current outside the math. An italic full stop looks like, or may be identical to the non italic font but it's a different glyph from a different font.

If you use any packages to reset the math or text fonts then it is quite common for the roman math font to be visually different to the text font, so there might be visible differences.

For a clearer example, a document using Arial (which has a square full stop) with lualatex:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

This sentence ends with a Arial dot.


This sentence ends with a cm dot
\[x=y.\]


This sentence ends with a Arial dot
\[x=y\text{.}\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: That said, if the symbol is identical in appearance between `$.$` and `.`, the spacing and positioning will be identical.

Comment: @DonHosek Are you sure that is the case?? Ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565517/txfonts-kerning-when-exiting-inline-math-mode

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes. The linked example is a very different case. `.` in math mode is going to grab the period from math font 0 which in a base distribution would be the same as the roman text font so metrics will line up. Enclosing the period in a box doesn't add any space so you get the exact same spacing. You can verify this by inspecting the DVI file¹ or overprinting the formulas in two different colors and zooming in to see if there's any of the bottom color peeking out around the edges if you zoom in on the output.

1. Although with `\text` you'll get *push*…*pop* around the `.`

Comment: Incidentally, I would be inclined to prefer `\textrm`, etc. over `\text` in pretty much all cases. Inheriting the surrounding typeface is seldom the desired result when text appears within math.

Comment: @DonHosek Thank you for those clarifications!

Comment: @DonHosek if the text is part of the math then yes `\textrm`, but here no. I intentionally used `\text` this is logically the same as `$x=y$.` with the `.` in the outer text font,  I'd normally try to avoid ending the sentence with a display but if it can't be avoided then even if the markup requires you to move it inside the display  then logically it makes sense to do anything possible to flag it as part of the puter sentence.