# Is $\text{.}$ and $.$ the same?

Tags: math-mode, equations

Is $\text{.}$ and $.$ the same?

I want to know this because I always write something like:

```
\begin{equation}
1+1=2\text{.}
\end{equation}
```

But if they are the same, then I can write:

```
\begin{equation}
1+1=2.
\end{equation}
```

Comment: It mostly depends on the surrounding font. See [When ending a sentence with the period, does it matter if the period is in maths mode or not?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/630010/5764) (possible duplicate).

Comment: If the text and math fonts are the same, they will appear the same, but, for example, load `newpxmath`, and typeset `\begin{equation}
1+1=2\text{.}.
\end{equation}`...the dots are of slightly different size.

Comment: @Werner Yes. I think my question is a duplicate. I don't know the policies of this site very well. What should I do with this question?