# Why are some math glyphs different from text glyphs when using STIX2?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, math-fonts, stix

When using STIX2 fonts for both text and math, some glyphs in math mode differ from those of text mode. For example, `$zuvw$` produces different glyphs than `\emph{zuvw}`:

[image: Sample output]

**Q:** Why is this so, and it is possible to change this, so that math mode glyphs are the same as in text mode?

I note that in the font file `STIX2Math.otf` both versions of the glyphs are present. Thus, I believe that the default behavior is according to general principles of design of math fonts, and *not* a bug.

MWE, assuming that the STIX2 OpenType fonts reside in the specified path:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math}[
Extension={.otf},
Path=./STIX2fonts/,
Scale=1]
\setmainfont{STIX2Text}[
Extension={.otf},
Path=./STIX2fonts/,
UprightFont={*-Regular},
BoldFont={*-Bold},
ItalicFont={*-Italic},
BoldItalicFont={*-BoldItalic}]

\begin{document}
\verb|$zuvw$|: $zuvw$, \verb|\emph{zuvw}|: \emph{zuvw}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on the site, please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. Then everybody is on the same page and we don't have to guess exactly what you are doing.

Comment: This happens also with Computer Modern. Math mode letters and italic text letters are not necessarily the same. They're different fonts; similar, yes, but not equal.

Comment: See e.g https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565517/82917 for a closely related issue.

Comment: Thanks for comments! I added a MWE. I do *not* think this is a bug, but a feature, but I would like to know if there are simple ways to fix it, e.g., by changing which glyph belongs to $z$, etc.

Comment: You are using different fonts for text and math, use `\mathit` to use the text italic font

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation of STIX Two (`texdoc stixtwomath`) shows a suitable stylistic set for “uvwz” like the italic STIX Two, but unfortunately, also the `g` would change to a shape *different* from the italic one.

[image]

Therefore, some juggling with ranges is necessary.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  range={`u,`v,`w,`z,"1D462,"1D463,"1D464,"1D467},
  StylisticSet=02,
]

\begin{document}

\verb|$zuvwg$|: $zuvwg$, \verb|\emph{zuvwg}|: \emph{zuvwg}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The italic z with a curly tail, although traditional in Times, isn't really appropriate for math, as it can pose problems with attaching subscripts or under-markings.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know, but I answered the OP's question… 